# How to trim input audio by FFMPEG?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

The below command well works for trimming the output audio

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -af silenceremove=1:0:-50dB output.mp3
```

However, I am concating several mp3 files,

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mp3 -i 2.mp3 -i 3.mp3 -filter_complex 'concat=n=3:v=0:a=1' out.mp3
```

and I need to trim the input audio before `concat`.

Is it possible to trim input audio before concating in `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ffmpeg \
    -i 1.mp3 \
    -i 2.mp3 \
    -i 3.mp3 \
    -filter_complex '[1]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a1];\
                     [2]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a2];\
                     [3]silenceremove=1:0:-50dB[a3];\
                     [a1][0][a2][0][a3]concat=n=5:v=0:a=1' out.mp3
```

Source: [How to trim input audio in FFMPEG?](https://superuser.com/questions/1498772/how-to-trim-input-audio-in-ffmpeg)